# Why can a `constexpr` function produce different results at compile- and run-time?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, constexpr, c++-concepts

A colleague of mine showed me this shocking C++20 program:

```
#include <iostream>

constexpr int p(auto) { return 0; }
constexpr int q() { return p(0); }
constexpr int p(auto) requires true { return 1; }

static_assert(p(0) == 1);
static_assert(q() == 0);

int main()
{
    std::cout << q() << p(0) << '\n';
}
```

GCC cannot build it due to the error:

```
Error: symbol `_Z1pIiEiT_' is already defined
```

Clang builds the program successfully and prints `11`( https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1Gf5vj5oo ). So `static_assert(q() == 0)` was successfully checked, but `std::cout << q()` still printed `1`. How can this be?

Visual Studio 2019 16.10.4 behaves even more weirdly. In Release configuration it prints also `11`, and in Debug configuration it prints `00`. And here in both cases run-time values of functions differ from their compile-time values, verified by `static_assert`.

The only explanation I can think of is that all these are compiler bugs, and a `constexpr` function must always produce the same result at compile- and run-time. Is that right?

Comment: You have 2 overloads of p, with only one visible at the q point of cal.  There is going to be a mess with overloads and template instantiation.  I suspect ill formed ndr.  q has different meaning at definition spot and at end of compilation unit.  Usually that is bad.

Comment: Thanks. I actually expected that if the compiler can check all function results in compile-time as `static_assert`s prove, why it cannot use the same values in run time?

Comment: The freedom to pick evaluate which overload selected at either point of definition or end of compilation unit saves compilers complexity and time.  You are responsible to not violate that.  Sensible code organization; grouping non-adl overload definitions together, defining signatures before implmentations - makes that easy.  Tge sample code you provided is bad code, and compliers choke on it.

Comment: Could you please crarify, what you mean by "bad code"? Yes, the code does not look practical, but only to simplify and reduce it for the purpose of this discussion. If the code violates something from the standard, please explain it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this program is contrived, it is **valid** and does what you think (prints “01”), so all compilers are wrong.  GCC is failing to **mangle** the `requires true` into the name of the second `p`, MSVC/Debug is failing to **select** that more-constrained overload, and the other two cases are failing to use the **lookup** result from `q` (which is not itself a template subject to multiple points of instantiation).

As for the question title, `std::is_constant_evaluated` does **allow** constant evaluation to produce different results from runtime evaluation.  Use this power only for good!

Comment: Template function bodies must evaluate to the same meaning at their definition amd end of compilation unit, no?

Comment: Hmm, only for adl purposes.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont: What “template function” do you mean?

Comment: `p` and `q` are template functions.  `auto` arguments make them template functions.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont `q` is not a template.

Comment: @xskxzr True,  Just `p`.